# How to read the labeled enron dataset categories?

Tags: classification, nlp, dataset, feature-engineering

I am trying to use the labeled Enron dataset ([link](https://data.world/brianray/enron-email-dataset)) but I am really confused about the labeling system they use. I understand the `Cat_[1-12]_level_weight` is some form of confidence level. This dataset labeled by multiple students. `Cat_[1-12]_level_weight` increases with the number of the same label assigned by multiple students to a certain row (sample). But, what is for instance the `Cat_1_level_2`? From the overview (in the [link](https://data.world/brianray/enron-email-dataset)), I guess `Cat_1` mean "*Course genre*" and `level_2` mean  "*Purely Personal (49 cnt.)*" ? If so, why the `Cat_1_level_2` has values like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.? I am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess here how it should be read. A sample could be in multiple categories. First, you look into a sample. Below is an example (at row 12) and the mail content:

| Content | Cat_1_level_1 | Cat_1_level_2 | Cat_1_weight | Cat_2_level_1 | Cat_2_level_2 | Cat_2_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jennifer, Thank-you for stepping in on this and guiding the process! ---------------------- Forwarded by Sarah-Joy Hunter/NA/Enron on 12/12/2000 05:03 PM --------------------------- From: Patrick Tucker@ENRON COMMUNICATIONS on 12/12/2000 02:52 PM PST To: Sarah-Joy Hunter/NA/Enron@ENRON cc: Subject: Re: HP -- confidential internal document Sarah-Joy, thanks for your excellent recap of progress to date. I really appreciate the organization and order you have brought to this process. It's great to work with you again after all of this time! Patrick | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 2 |

Here, you need to combine the `Cat_1_level_*` to get a single category that this mail belongs to. You can do the same combination for other categories as well (like `Cat_2_level_*`). If you combine the first category as `Cat_1_level_1` (which is 1) and `Cat_2_level_2` (which is 2), you get an actual category label which is Category 1.2 (Purely personal). As I said before, a sample could be in multiple categories. If you combine the second category labels, the `Cat_2_level_1` (which is 4) and `Cat_2_level_2` (which is 6), you get another category label which is Category 4.6 (gratitude). If you check the content, you can see they are talking about something personal and they try to express how grateful they are to each other.

About the weights (`Cat_1_weight`, `Cat_2_weight`, `Cat_*_weight`...). Since this dataset samples were labeled by multiple people,  in some cases, there were different labels assigned to the same sample (or in some cases a sample assigned with the same label by multiple people). The weights show that how many people assigned the same label in a category for a certain sample. Here, the `Cat_1_weight` is `2`, which means 2 people assigned this `Cat_1_level_*` labels to this sample. (I guess...)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [first link](https://data.world/brianray/enron-email-dataset) from your post there is an in-depth overview of the different categories. `Cat_#_level_1` denotes the top level category (12 in total) whereas `Cat_#_level_2` denotes the second level category (up to 19 categories, depending on the level 1 category). E.g. an email with the labels `Cat_3_level_1` and `Cat_6_level_2` has the label `california energy crisis / california politics` (category 3.6). You therefore need to combine the two levels to get to the label that belongs to the second level category.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you

Comment: If my answer solved your question please mark my answer as the solution for other who may have the same question.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but not that much. So, there is an email with label 2 in the column of Cat_3_level_1. What does that 2 mean?

Comment: From what I understand, first, I need to look at the `Cat_#_level_1`. From my example, it is `2`. And from there, I need to look at the `Cat_2_level_2` because `Cat_1_level_1` is `2`. And in that email, the `Cat_2_level_2` is `3`. Does that mean this email belongs to category 2.3??... Omg I have no idea